# Parsing error: Unexptected token => eslint

Tags: javascript, firebase, eslint

I googled and tried out different approaches, but it seems that the async function causes an error saying that the `=>` is unexpected. I tried adding the ecmaVersion to the .eslintrc.js but with no result.

My code:

```
exports.badgeUpdated = functions.firestore
    .document("badges/{docId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, _) => {
      //get the document that has changed and the new fieldvalue
      const newObjectId = change.after.id;
      const newObject = change.after.data();
      const newBadgeName = newObject.badgeName;
      console.log(`New BadgeName ${newBadgeName}`);
      //Search badge doc with changed ID and set new name
      const badgedRef = admin
        .firestore()
        .collectionGroup("badgeCollection")
        .where("id", "==", newObjectId).get();
      console.log(`Queryresult ${(await badgedRef).docs}`);
      return null;
});
```

The linter is complaining about the third line.
My .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2022,
    },
    "sourceType": "module",
  },
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
  },

};
```

Comment: What exactly is the error, in full? ESLint usually tells you which rule you're violating

Comment: FYI, the `, _` is redundant, you can simply use `async (change) =>`. Are you sure it's not complaining about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ecmaVersion` should not be in `ecmaFeatures`.

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    "ecmaVersion": 2022,
    "sourceType": "module",
  },
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],
  },
};
```

Also, please make sure that you are using the latest version of ESLint.